# how can I write right the line of code *(node_pointer)->n

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following struct (with a typedef to a pointer of that struct):

```
 typedef struct node_t* Node;

 struct node_t {
 int n;
 Node next;
 };
```

and within a function , Im using the type Node* in the following way:

```
Node* node_pointer;
Node new_node=malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
while(node1!=NULL && node2!=NULL) {
        node_pointer=((node1->n)>(node2->n) ? &node1, &node2);
        new_node->n=*(node_pointer)->n;
        *(node_pointer)=*(node_pointer)->next;
        new_node->next=malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
        new_node=new_node->next;
}
```

and apparently, the expression *(pointer to pointer of
 struct)->field  is illegal. how to write it right while keeping it simple?

Comment: `new_node->n=*(node_pointer)->n;` -->> `new_node->n=(*node_pointer)->n;` (And also: strong advice not to hide pointers behind typedefs) Extra: you malloc() twice: once before the loop and once inside it. That looks overly complex to me; what would happen if the loop was executed zero times?

Comment: Did you try *((node_pointer)->n)? You are trying to deference the pointer (grab contents of) and then point to something within the structure I believe.

Comment: `node_pointer=((node1->n)>(node2->n) ? &node1, &node2);` -->> the comma is probably intended as a `:`, and you dont need all those `()`

Comment: Very strong recommendation: Don't `typecast` pointers! This hides the semantics and eventually causes confusion.

Answer (score -1):

plz try this code:
`(*nodepointer)-> n`

Comment: sorry, didn't see it first time